# Конфигуратор персонажа как в симсах, но на сайте =)

Tags: javascript, html, анимация

Нужно сделать на сайте что-то вроде конструктора персонажа, как в симсах, то есть слева некое существо(3d или видео), немного анимированное (gif? / секвенция кадров? / видео? что лучше), типо стоит переминается, или какое то минимальное движение рук/моргание, справа конфигуратор, типа заходишь в режим лица, слева персонаж увеличивается до лица, в конфигураторе наводишь на нос, слева у персонажа накладывается нос итд, думаю смысл понятен.

**Вопрос:** как лучше такое реализовывать?

**Какие есть мысли у меня к подходу:**

снять человека на видео(или замоделить это все), разложить на кадры, и кадры двигать через js, но боюсь будет огромный файл, если туда все возможные позиции движений закидывать. разбивать файлы по смыслу, и подгружать аяксом - тут два минуса вижу, первый это попадание в стык между анимациями, и второй это возможно долгая подгрузка, что не айс, навел, например, в конфигураторе на лицо, и прогресс бар вращается и вращается - вообщем не хочется такого. Какие есть еще мысли, как можно наиболее грамотно реалицовать сие, чтобы и легковесно было и чтобы правильно работало?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону 3D и WebGL. Или 2D и компоновку накладываемых картинок (а-ля шапки и прочие предметы в играх на планшетах)

Comment: Спасибо! Тут смысл не в реализации накладки, так как удобнее все варианты типа носов итд, запечь в файл, а вопрос как между кусками анимации перемещаться, какой подход выбрать, чтобы не тяжело было сайту.

Comment: "***удобнее** все варианты типа носов итд, запечь в файл*" - это утверждение выглядит сомнительно.

Comment: понимаете, там просто должна быть качественная анимация каждого ействия, а наложение это статика

Comment: Без подробностей, сложно что-то сказать точнее.

Comment: Для вашей цели лучше всего подойдет разработка под WebGL на движке Unity3D. Для старта можете прочесть следующую статью:
[Создаем игру для WebGL с помощью Unity 5 и JavaScript](https://habrahabr.ru/company/plarium/blog/312318/)